# What's the time complexity to get the number of nodes under given root in AVL tree and balanced binary trees?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, avl-tree

To search a certain node in AVL tree and balanced binary tree, it takes O(logn) time. Can I get the number of nodes which under this certain node in O(logn) time, too? If so, please elaborate. Pseudocode would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a 'size' field in each nodes that keeps to size of the sub-tree that the nodes is it's root.

The implementation is that in each method of the tree you keep that field updated.

And the update is always: Father.size = SonA.size+SonB.size

Now the implementation itself is in every method of the tree, to call to the update method that I presented above in the relevant nodes.

Comment: My goal is to count the number of terms in a pile of data that are not larger than the given term in O(logn) time. Can this achieved by using AVL tree or the binary tree?

Comment: Yes. you need to locate where in the tree the given term is locate (or can be located).

then, as long as you are on right sons of some father you go up to the father and sum the size of the left son of that father.

in this way you sum the number of all terms that are not larger than the given term

Comment: I don't quite get it. Say we have a AVL tree:{8,3,2,6,5,7,14,11,15}. The given term is 6, I go to 6's father, 3. The size of 3's left son is 1(only 2 is the child of 3). But the answer should be 3.(2,3,5)

Comment: what the time complexity would be to update the size field when updating the tree.

Comment: I didnt want to make the comment too long, but indeed, there are some more details.
In your example: you start from 6, so you take the size of its left son (which is 5) . then, we are going up to 3, so we add the size of the left son of 3 and 3 itself. 
again we want to go up, but now 3 was a left son of 8, so we dont add anything. we keep going up adding the left son just when we moved from a right son to its father.

Comment: and the time complexity for updating sizes is constant because you need to know just the size of the two sons.
and for a rotation there is just a constant number of updating.
and for balancing, the number of updates is just as the number of balancing operations.

Comment: so in total the complexity preserver